# NDB query().iter() of 1000<n<1500 entities is wigging out

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a script that, using Remote API, iterates through all entities for a few models. Let's say two models, called `FooModel` with about 200 entities, and `BarModel` with about 1200 entities. Each has 15 `StringProperty`s.

```
for model in [FooModel, BarModel]:
    print 'Downloading {}'.format(model.__name__)
    new_items_iter = model.query().iter()
    new_items = [i.to_dict() for i in new_items_iter]
    print new_items
```

When I run this in my console, it hangs for a while after printing 'Downloading BarModel'. It hangs until I hit ctrl+C, at which point it prints the downloaded list of items.

When this is run in a Jenkins job, there's no one to press ctrl+C, so it just runs continuously (last night it ran for 6 hours before something, presumably Jenkins, killed it). Datastore activity logs reveal that the datastore was taking 5.5 API calls per second for the entire 6 hours, racking up a few dollars in GAE usage charges in the meantime.

Why is this happening? What's with the weird behavior of ctrl+C? Why is the iterator not finishing?

Comment: Since this is a known issue as indicated in the answer below, the questions above have been answered.  If you agree, please select it so this question may be considered resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue currently being tracked on the Google App Engine public issue tracker under [Issue 12908](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12908). The issue was forwarded to the engineering team and progress on this issue will be discussed on said thread. Should this be affecting you, please star the issue to receive updates.

In short, the issue appears to be with the `remote_api` script. When querying entities of a given kind, it will hang when fetching `1001 + batch_size` entities when the `batch_size` is specified. This does not happen in production outside of the `remote_api`.

### Possible workarounds

#### Using the `remote_api`

One could limit the number of entities fetched per script execution using the `limit` argument for [queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries). This may be somewhat tedious but the script could simply be executed repeatedly from another script to essentially have the same effect.

#### Using admin URLs

For repeated operations, it may be worthwhile to build a web UI accessible only to admins. This can be done with the help of the `users` module as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers). This is not really practical for a one-time task but far more robust for regular maintenance tasks. As this does not use the `remote_api` at all, one would not encounter this bug.